# Escaping output but allowing <p> in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, escaping, sanitization

In my Laravel app I allow users to store some text from a text area. When outputting the text I would like to escape the text retrieved from the DB, but also convert any line breaks from the text into `<p>` tags. I have a function `nl2p()` that works well for this, but it gets escaped when I place it inside the triple brackets defeating the purpose: `{{{ nl2p($bio) }}}`

I tried doing something like this:

```
<?php $formatted_bio = {{{ $user->bio }}}; ?>
<h2>{{ nl2p($formatted_bio) }}</h2>
```

but data can't be echoed into a variable like that. Any creative solutions out there I may have overlooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [`e()`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#strings) helper function Laravel provides. It is basically what Blade calls under the hood when you do the triple braces.
So you'd have:

```
<h2>{{ nl2p(e($user->bio)) }}</h2>
```